# Can you access an NTFS Windows portion with read write capabilities on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs

I'm thinking about switching to Ubuntu because I absolutely hate windows 10. I have a separate hdd  that has all of my media and games on it. If I install Ubuntu on my designated OS hdd can I access my media hdd from within Ubuntu and will I be able to have read/write capabilities?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu can read and write to Windows partitions by default, thanks to [ntfs-3g driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G). You can test it from an Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: 1 thing to add: disable hibernation on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. AFAIK all linuxes reads and writes just fine to NTFS partitions, as a matter of fact I formate most of my USB harddisks with Gparted as NTFS ! 
Why I hear you all ask?   Well you see our windows machines only support Fat  and NTFS - as do our settop boxes for the tellys, and I think thatv NTFS is better than FAT, at least it support large files- movies for viewing on the big screen or record them from the settopbox! This results in some mpeg2 files (transmission streams) somefiles.TS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. NTFS works fine with Ubuntu. If you plan to dual-boot windows and Ubuntu, I think NTFS would be your best choice of format because it would be readable on both.